# Use class as type in other class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

i would like to use a class Point in an other class Rect.

```
class Point
{
    int x, y;
    public:
    Point (int px, int py){
        x = px;
        y = py;
    }
};

class Rect
{
    Point top_left; 
    Point bottom_right;
    public:
    Rect (Point p1, Point p2){
        top_left = p1;
        bottom_right = p2;
    }
};
```

error message is: "**main.cpp:31:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘Rect::Point::Point()’**". In my understanding the constructor method of the Rect class uses two parameters of type Point to instantiate a Rect object. I guess that i cannot use "Point" as type since it sounds to me as the compiler wants to call a function. The error message doesn't help me so i hope you will. Thanks for that in advance.

Comment: Add a default constructor for class `Point`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when a `Rect` object is created, the member variables are constructed and initialized before the `Rect` constructor body is executed.

Since there's no explicit initialization of the `Point` member variables, they will need to be default constructible, which they aren't because you don't have a default `Point` constructor.

There are a couple of possible possible solutions, of which the simplest one is:

1. Create a `Point` default constructor. It doesn't have to do anything and can be compiler generated (but you must still tell the compiler to generate it):

   ```
   class Point
   {
   public:
       Point() = default;
       ...
   };
   ```

   While `Point` can now be default constructed, it will leave the `x` and `y` members uninitialized.

But I would rather recommend another solution:

2. Create a `Rect` constructor initializer list to initialize the member variables of `Rect`:

   ```
   class Rect
   {
       Point top_left; 
       Point bottom_right;

   public:
       Rect(Point p1, Point p2)
           : top_left(p1), bottom_right(p2)
       {
           // Empty
       }
       ...
   };
   ```

With the second solution no `Point` default constructor is needed.

---

As for why there's no default constructor created for `Point`, it's because you have declared another constructor. That prohibits the compiler from generating its own default constructor (without being told to do so as in the first alternative).

Comment: Notice that default constructor for `Point` lets its fields uninitialized.

Answer (score 5):

Members are initialized before the body of the constructor runs. When you write:

```
Rect (Point p1, Point p2){
    top_left = p1;
    bottom_right = p2;
}
```

Then before the constructor is executed the members `top_left` and `bottom_right` are initialized. Because `Point` has no default constructor the members cannot be initialized.

To initialize members with a constructor you should use the member initializer list:

```
Rect (Point p1, Point p2) : top_left(p1), bottom_right(p2) { }
```

The error can be prevented also by providing default initializers for the members:

```
class Rect
{
    Point top_left{0,0}; 
    Point bottom_right{0,0};
    public:
    Rect (Point p1, Point p2){
        top_left = p1;
        bottom_right = p2;
    }
};
```

Or by providing a default constructor for `Point`. A default constructor is one that can be called without parameters. However, in any case you should prefer the member initializer list over assignment in the constructor body, because initialization + assignment is more expensive than initialization only.

Answer (score -2):

In your given example, the data members `top_left` and `bottom_right` are **default initialized** before the body of `Rect::Rect (Point, Point)` gets executed. This means in your example for the statements:

```
Point top_left; //this statement needs default ctor in your example because this data member is default initialized 
Point bottom_right;//this statement needs default ctor in your example because this data member is default initialized
```

to work the default constructor `Point::Point()` is required.

But the **problem** is that since you've user-defined constructor for your class `Point`, the compiler will not synthesize the **default ctor** `Point::Point()`.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem.

##### Solution 1

First is that you can add a default constructor for class `Point` as shown below:

```
class Point
{
    int x, y;
    public:
        Point (int px, int py){
            x = px;
            y = py;
        }
        //default constructor
        Point(): x(0), y(0){
        }
};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/v8AoZAWiu).

In the above modified code, i've added a default constructor that uses **constructor initializer list** to initialize the data members `x` and `y`.

##### Solution 2

We can also use **constructor initializer list** in the constructor `Rect::Rect(Point, Point)` to initialize the data members by passing arguments instead of default initializing them.

```
class Rect
{
    Point top_left; 
    Point bottom_right;
    public:
    //use constructor initializer list to intialize the data members by passing arguments instead of default initializing them
    Rect (Point p1, Point p2): top_left(p1), bottom_right(p2){
       
    }
};
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-z9BKjmLQ).